# Flask - multiple client upload

Tags: python, flask

I have a basic flask app for uploading image files to server and then rendering on webpage.
When multiple clients upload, in current design they end up overwriting the same static assets. What is the best approach when uploads from multiple clients are to be handled in flask?

Comment: Can you provide some code ? What are the routes ? How do you make difference between a user and another user ? We need more details on how you made your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. first, u must rename and make safe the name (without space and fobidden character) of file. so every file name can be unique.

```
def unique_name(data):
    file = data.filename
    ext = file.split('.')[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4().hex, ext)
    return filename

#or 

from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
```

2. pass the value of name of image from form to this function, ie:

```
DataModel(photo_filename=unique_name(form.photo.data))
# or
DataModel(photo_filename=secure_filename(form.photo.data))
```

hopefully answer your questions

Comment: thanks for the advice, can you please elaborate what the DataModel would be

Comment: data model just models. if you dont know how to implement, i reference flask-sqlalchemy : https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/ or you can see i have old code on github here https://github.com/dvrg/flask-upload-image/blob/master/app.py